# VBA checking if file exist using notepad

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to ask the community if there is anyway someone can store file directories path into a notepad or other word document and let VBA scan through each file directories and check if file exist.

Comment: The answer to your question is yes. You need to save it as text actually then read that `.txt` file line by line using VBA and then use `DIR function` probably from there to test if the file or directory exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a commented code that uses `dir` to illustrate the comment above.

```
'This function will check if the file or the directory
'exists and returns a boolean.
Function ExistTest(Path As String) As Boolean
'The function default return is set to false
ExistTest = False
'Remove stream reader appending
Path = Replace(Path, "ï»¿", "")
'Dir returns a 0-length string if the file or directory doesn't exist
If Len(Dir(Path)) > 0 Or Len(Dir(Path, vbDirectory)) > 0 Then
ExistTest = True
End If
End Function

Sub main()
'Defining the source file
Dim SourceFile As String: SourceFile = "d:/t.txt"
'Open a stream reader
Open SourceFile For Input As #1
'Read all line until the end of file
'Before we define a temporary string the path as we go through
'the sourcefile
Dim TempPath As String
Do Until EOF(1)
Line Input #1, TempPath
'Debug print the results
Debug.Print (TempPath & " " & ExistTest(TempPath))
Loop
Close #1
End Sub
```

`Debug.Print` will print in the **immediate window**. To enable that, go to View > Immediate Window